# How do test the side effects of an except block with pytest?

Tags: python-3.x, testing, exception, pytest

My goal is to throw an exception during a test to trigger an except block, then wait for the except block to complete, and then assert stuff.

This is the method that needs to be tested

```
def main(args, symbol_store):
    t = None
    try:
        t = parse_and_download(args.output, args.symbols, symbol_store)
        t.wait()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        if t is not None:
            t.set()
            print(string_downloads_cancelled, flush=True)
```

The test method should do something like this

```
raise KeyboardInterrupt
assert not os.path.exists(test_symbol_store)
```

The assertion is clearly unreachable, and even if it was, I am certain that it would not wait for the except block to complete.

Following the advice of MrBean Breman I mocked the wait function with pytest_mocker.

```
    mocker.patch('main.DownloadManager.DownloadThread.wait', side_effect=KeyboardInterrupt)
```

This works as intended.

Comment: Have you tried to patch `t.wait` to raise the exception?

Comment: I am not familiar with patching

Comment: I am guessing you are talking about mocking the function.

Comment: Yes, mocking can be done via `mock.patch`, thus "patching".